# Count particular key value from array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, object

I have following JSON array I want to create object form status key count

```
[
  {
    "id": "65:0",    
    "status": "ORANGE"
  },
  {
    "id": "65:0",
    "status": "GREEN"
  },
  {
    "id": "65:0",
    "status": "ORANGE"
  },
  {
    "id": "65:0",
    "status": "YELLOW"
  },
  {
    "id": "65:0",
    "status": "RED"
  },
  {
    "id": "65:0",
    "status": "GREEN"
  },
  {
    "id": "65:0",
    "status": "GREEN"
  },
   {
    "id": "65:0",
    "status": "ORANGE"
  },
  {
    "id": "65:0",
    "status": "YELLOW"
  },
  {
    "id": "65:0",
    "status": "GREEN"
  }
]
```

Want to count status key value and create the following Object

```
{
 'ORANGE' : 3,
 'GREEN' : 4,
 'YELLOW' : 2,
 'RED' : 1,
}
```

Comment: what is the problem then?

Comment: FYI, use `array.filter`, `array.map`, `array.reduce`, etc. They will help loads.

Comment: This may also help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24252305/using-array-reduce-method-to-count-duplicate-elements

Comment: Please help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72084738/count-object-based-on-status-and-shop-using-javascript

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use **[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** method

```
var res = data.reduce(function(obj, v) {
  // increment or set the property
  // `(obj[v.status] || 0)` returns the property value if defined
  // or 0 ( since `undefined` is a falsy value
  obj[v.status] = (obj[v.status] || 0) + 1;
  // return the updated object
  return obj;
  // set the initial value as an object
}, {})
```

```js
var data = [{
  "id": "65:0",
  "status": "ORANGE"
}, {
  "id": "65:0",
  "status": "GREEN"
}, {
  "id": "65:0",
  "status": "ORANGE"
}, {
  "id": "65:0",
  "status": "YELLOW"
}, {
  "id": "65:0",
  "status": "RED"
}, {
  "id": "65:0",
  "status": "GREEN"
}, {
  "id": "65:0",
  "status": "GREEN"
}, {
  "id": "65:0",
  "status": "ORANGE"
}, {
  "id": "65:0",
  "status": "YELLOW"
}, {
  "id": "65:0",
  "status": "GREEN"
}];

var res = data.reduce(function(obj, v) {
  obj[v.status] = (obj[v.status] || 0) + 1;
  return obj;
}, {})

console.log(res);
```

---

Although you can use **[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** method with the same code.

```
var res = {};
data.forEach(function(v) {
  res[v.status] = (res[v.status] || 0) + 1;
})
```

```js
var data = [{
  "id": "65:0",
  "status": "ORANGE"
}, {
  "id": "65:0",
  "status": "GREEN"
}, {
  "id": "65:0",
  "status": "ORANGE"
}, {
  "id": "65:0",
  "status": "YELLOW"
}, {
  "id": "65:0",
  "status": "RED"
}, {
  "id": "65:0",
  "status": "GREEN"
}, {
  "id": "65:0",
  "status": "GREEN"
}, {
  "id": "65:0",
  "status": "ORANGE"
}, {
  "id": "65:0",
  "status": "YELLOW"
}, {
  "id": "65:0",
  "status": "GREEN"
}];

var res = {};
data.forEach(function(v) {
  res[v.status] = (res[v.status] || 0) + 1;
})

console.log(res);
```

Comment: could you tell me how to push the output to object array so we can use it later (in your Array#forEach method )?Thanks

Comment: @user1788736 :  what you mean by object array... something like `[{...},{...},....]`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Yes like this [{statusType:"orange",statusSize:3},{statusType:"green",statusSize:4},{..}..]. I tried this inside for each loop but it did not store those information MyObjectArray.push({
                   statusType: res[v.status],
                   statusSize: (res[v.status] || 0) + 1
              });

Comment: @user1788736 :  share your data

Comment: var MyObjectArray = [
{userId:"10",userName:"david",displayUrl:"https://www.somesite.com/1david.jpg"},
{userId:"12",userName:"edward",displayUrl:"https://www.somesite.com/1edward.jpg"},
{userId:"10",userName:"david",displayUrl:"https://www.somesite.com/2david.jpg"},
{userId:"12",userName:"edward",displayUrl:"https://www.somesite.com/2edward.jpg"},
{userId:"10",userName:"david",displayUrl:"https://www.somesite.com/3david.jpg"}
];
and i want to push this info to another object array:

var MyNewObjectArray =[
{userId:10,repeatedTimes:3},{userId:12,repeatedTimes:2}]

Comment: @user1788736 `let ref = {};
let res = [];

data.forEach(function(o) {
  if (!(o.userId in ref))
    res[ref[o.userId] = res.length] = {
      userId: o.userId,
      repeatedTimes: 0
    }
  res[ref[o.userId]].repeatedTimes++;
})

console.log(res);`

Comment: can i use var instead of let for decaring the object arrays ? i want to be able to use them in other functions as well?

Comment: @user1788736 : yeah sure u can

Comment: Please help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72084738/count-object-based-on-status-and-shop-using-javascript

Answer (score 4):

```js
var obj = [
  {
    "id": "65:0",    
    "status": "ORANGE"
  },
  {
    "id": "65:0",
    "name": "BIU",
    "status": "GREEN"
  },
  {
    "id": "65:0",
    "name": "BIU",
    "status": "ORANGE"
  },
  {
    "id": "65:0",
    "status": "YELLOW"
  },
  {
    "id": "65:0",
    "status": "RED"
  },
  {
    "id": "65:0",
    "status": "GREEN"
  },
  {
    "id": "65:0",
    "status": "GREEN"
  },
   {
    "id": "65:0",
    "status": "ORANGE"
  },
  {
    "id": "65:0",
    "status": "YELLOW"
  },
  {
    "id": "65:0",
    "status": "GREEN"
  }
] ;

var rez={};
obj.forEach(function(item){
  rez[item.status] ? rez[item.status]++ :  rez[item.status] = 1;
});
console.log(rez);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this output format?

```js
var json=[
  {
    "id": "65:0",    
    "status": "ORANGE"
  },
  {
    "id": "65:0",
    "status": "GREEN"
  },
  {
    "id": "65:0",
    "status": "ORANGE"
  },
  {
    "id": "65:0",
    "status": "YELLOW"
  },
  {
    "id": "65:0",
    "status": "RED"
  },
  {
    "id": "65:0",
    "status": "GREEN"
  },
  {
    "id": "65:0",
    "status": "GREEN"
  },
   {
    "id": "65:0",
    "status": "ORANGE"
  },
  {
    "id": "65:0",
    "status": "YELLOW"
  },
  {
    "id": "65:0",
    "status": "GREEN"
  }
] ;

var obj={};
json.forEach(function(item){
obj[item.status]? obj[item.status]++ : obj[item.status]=1;
});

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Nice way, but only works if it's in sorted order(sorted based on `status` property).. specify that in your answer...

Comment: yeh, I can not use index over there. I updated my code:P.