# How filtering works in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how to filter data from the following array

```
0: {Id: 30008, Item: " Rice"}
1: {Id: 30009, Item: " Beans"}
2: {Id: 30011, Item: " Beans"}
3: {Id: 30016, Item: " Rice"}"
```

I would like to get the count of all items that are repeating in the above. My idea is get the count and append this number in some div in the page. The page contains the following div

```
<div className="quantity">
    <input type="number" defaultValue="{1}" min="{1}" className="quantity-field" id="default-quantity" />
</div>
```

Comment: Filtering and counting are two different things. Which do you need? What have you tried?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38694939/count-particular-key-value-from-array-of-object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: filter() for Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072136/javascript-filter-for-objects)

Comment: I am trying to filter and show just the single items and the count. For example 
Rice 2 and Beans 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `reduce` for collect and count your items, like this:

```
const data = [{Id: 30008, Item: " Rice"},
{Id: 30009, Item: " Beans"},
{Id: 30011, Item: " Beans"},
{Id: 30016, Item: " Rice"}]

const groupedDataObj = data.reduce((acc,rec)=>{
    acc[rec.Item] = typeof acc[rec.Item] === 'undefined'? 1: acc[rec.Item]+1
    return {...acc}
},{})

const groupedDataArray = Object.keys(groupedDataObj).map((key)=>({[key]: groupedDataObj[key]}))
```

See full example in the playground: https://jscomplete.com/playground/s545971